# LARAVEL After refreshing my database i am getting issues with not finding the parameters in my routes

Tags: php, laravel

Everything was working with all my routes until i refreshed my database, from then on i can create a new account fine but then after that it keeps on throwing me this error

> Missing required parameter for [Route: login] [URI: {locale}/login] [Missing parameter: locale].

The routes for authentication

```
use Laravel\Fortify\Http\Controllers\PasswordController;
use Laravel\Fortify\Http\Controllers\PasswordResetLinkController;
use Laravel\Fortify\Http\Controllers\ProfileInformationController;
use Laravel\Fortify\Http\Controllers\RecoveryCodeController;
use Laravel\Fortify\Http\Controllers\RegisteredUserController;
use Laravel\Fortify\Http\Controllers\TwoFactorAuthenticatedSessionController;
use Laravel\Fortify\Http\Controllers\TwoFactorAuthenticationController;
use Laravel\Fortify\Http\Controllers\TwoFactorQrCodeController;
use Laravel\Fortify\Http\Controllers\VerifyEmailController;

Route::group(['middleware' => config('fortify.middleware', ['web']), 'prefix' => '{locale}'], function () {
    $enableViews = config('fortify.views', true);

    // Authentication...

    if ($enableViews) {
        Route::get('/login', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'create'])
            ->middleware(['guest:'.config('fortify.guard')])
            ->name('login');
    }

    $limiter = config('fortify.limiters.login');
    $twoFactorLimiter = config('fortify.limiters.two-factor');

    Route::post('/login', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'store'])
        ->middleware(array_filter([
            'guest:'.config('fortify.guard'),
            $limiter ? 'throttle:'.$limiter : null,
        ]));

    Route::post('/logout', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'destroy'])
        ->name('logout');

    // Password Reset...
    if (Features::enabled(Features::resetPasswords())) {
        if ($enableViews) {
            Route::get('/forgot-password', [PasswordResetLinkController::class, 'create'])
                ->middleware(['guest:'.config('fortify.guard')])
                ->name('password.request');

            Route::get('/reset-password/{token}', [NewPasswordController::class, 'create'])
                ->middleware(['guest:'.config('fortify.guard')])
                ->name('password.reset');
        }

        Route::post('/forgot-password', [PasswordResetLinkController::class, 'store'])
            ->middleware(['guest:'.config('fortify.guard')])
            ->name('password.email');

        Route::post('/reset-password', [NewPasswordController::class, 'store'])
            ->middleware(['guest:'.config('fortify.guard')])
            ->name('password.update');
    }

    // Registration...
    if (Features::enabled(Features::registration())) {
        if ($enableViews) {
            Route::get('/register', [RegisteredUserController::class, 'create'])
                ->middleware(['guest:'.config('fortify.guard')])
                ->name('register');
        }

        Route::post('/register', [RegisteredUserController::class, 'store'])
            ->middleware(['guest:'.config('fortify.guard')]);
    }

    // Email Verification...
    if (Features::enabled(Features::emailVerification())) {
        if ($enableViews) {
            Route::get('/email/verify', [EmailVerificationPromptController::class, '__invoke'])
                ->middleware(['auth'])
                ->name('verification.notice');
        }

        Route::get('/email/verify/{id}/{hash}', [VerifyEmailController::class, '__invoke'])
            ->middleware(['auth', 'signed', 'throttle:6,1'])
            ->name('verification.verify');

        Route::post('/email/verification-notification', [EmailVerificationNotificationController::class, 'store'])
            ->middleware(['auth', 'throttle:6,1'])
            ->name('verification.send');
    }

    // Profile Information...
    if (Features::enabled(Features::updateProfileInformation())) {
        Route::put('/user/profile-information', [ProfileInformationController::class, 'update'])
            ->middleware(['auth'])
            ->name('user-profile-information.update');
    }

    // Passwords...
    if (Features::enabled(Features::updatePasswords())) {
        Route::put('/user/password', [PasswordController::class, 'update'])
            ->middleware(['auth'])
            ->name('user-password.update');
    }

    // Password Confirmation...
    if ($enableViews) {
        Route::get('/user/confirm-password', [ConfirmablePasswordController::class, 'show'])
            ->middleware(['auth'])
            ->name('password.confirm');
    }

    Route::get('/user/confirmed-password-status', [ConfirmedPasswordStatusController::class, 'show'])
        ->middleware(['auth'])
        ->name('password.confirmation');

    Route::post('/user/confirm-password', [ConfirmablePasswordController::class, 'store'])
        ->middleware(['auth']);

    // Two Factor Authentication...
    if (Features::enabled(Features::twoFactorAuthentication())) {
        if ($enableViews) {
            Route::get('/two-factor-challenge', [TwoFactorAuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'create'])
                ->middleware(['guest:'.config('fortify.guard')])
                ->name('two-factor.login');
        }

        Route::post('/two-factor-challenge', [TwoFactorAuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'store'])
            ->middleware(array_filter([
                'guest:'.config('fortify.guard'),
                $twoFactorLimiter ? 'throttle:'.$twoFactorLimiter : null,
            ]));

        $twoFactorMiddleware = Features::optionEnabled(Features::twoFactorAuthentication(), 'confirmPassword')
            ? ['auth', 'password.confirm']
            : ['auth'];

        Route::post('/user/two-factor-authentication', [TwoFactorAuthenticationController::class, 'store'])
            ->middleware($twoFactorMiddleware)
            ->name('two-factor.enable');

        Route::delete('/user/two-factor-authentication', [TwoFactorAuthenticationController::class, 'destroy'])
            ->middleware($twoFactorMiddleware)
            ->name('two-factor.disable');

        Route::get('/user/two-factor-qr-code', [TwoFactorQrCodeController::class, 'show'])
            ->middleware($twoFactorMiddleware)
            ->name('two-factor.qr-code');

        Route::get('/user/two-factor-recovery-codes', [RecoveryCodeController::class, 'index'])
            ->middleware($twoFactorMiddleware)
            ->name('two-factor.recovery-codes');

        Route::post('/user/two-factor-recovery-codes', [RecoveryCodeController::class, 'store'])
            ->middleware($twoFactorMiddleware);
    }
});
```

The set locale middleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SetLocale
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (auth()->user()) {
            app()->setlocale(auth()->user()->locale);
        } else {
            app()->setlocale($request->locale);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

The Authenticate middleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;

class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string|null
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('login', app()->getLocale());
        }
    }
}
```

The user model that gets created before the errors just to show that the user has a locale and gets created before the whole thing errors out

```
sail artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.10.8 (PHP 8.0.5 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> User::all()
[!] Aliasing 'User' to 'App\Models\User' for this Tinker session.
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#4450
     all: [
       App\Models\User {#4383
         id: 1,
         name: "Daniel Gordon",
         email: "dg@gmail.com",
         email_verified_at: null,
         #password: "$2y$10$a3FlHMZ7accfWyeUGdEA3.1KTQ9Jh/wi5b0aztZNtPQfBQiOYhkT2",
         #two_factor_secret: null,
         #two_factor_recovery_codes: null,
         #remember_token: null,
         current_team_id: null,
         profile_photo_path: null,
         created_at: "2021-06-13 18:03:43",
         updated_at: "2021-06-13 18:03:43",
         locale: "en",
         +profile_photo_url: "",
       },
     ],
   }
```

and idk how useful this last part is but just incase the only addition to my migration files

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AddColumnsToProducts extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('custom_name');
            $table->string('currency');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('custom_name');
            $table->dropColumn('currency');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: It also throws me the error if i manually type in the url localhost/en/login

Answer (score 0):

Your middleware is not correct, you should be doing this:

```php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;

class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string|null
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('login', ['locale' => app()->getLocale()]);
        }
    }
}
```

Read how the helper [`route`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-route) works...

Comment: No this should be working as internally it uses array indexed and wraps it. in respect to the ordering of the URL parameters. I'm guessing that the app()->locale() is not returning properly. see example of it working as he used it.
php artisan tinker
>>> route('test', 'dk');
=> "http://localhost/dk/test"